# Service that stays alive after app closure and doesn't lock the UI

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service, intentservice

In my Android project I have the necessity to start a `Service` that:

1. Stays alive even after the application closure
2. Doesn't block the main Thread

I analyzed Services, IntentServices and Threads for this issue:

Using a `Service` and overriding

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // Some nasty code
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

I achieve the first goal, but I block the Main Thread when I start the service

Using an `IntentService` and overriding

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    // Same nasty code as before
}
```

I achieve the second goal, cause I don't block the UI but the service dies when I kill the application.

Then I tried to start a `Thread` using a `Service`, like this:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //The usual nasty code
        }
    });
    thread.start();
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

And I achieve the same result as the first case (I block the UI).

I start the service with `myActivity.startService(myActivity, MyService.class)`

Am I missing something obvious? Is ther a way to achieve both the goals?

Comment: Unlike windows Services, Android Services run in the starter's Thread. So if you start a service, you need to create a Thread and return immediately. Then UI is not (for long) blocked. Then communicate with the service to delegate work to it. There is a big chapter on all of this in the developer docs - check them out : http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: The Problem with your Thread may be that you created it in onStartCommand. On the page I linked above there is a complete example of a started Service with a Workerthread created in "onCreate". And using HandlerThread and Looper classes.

Comment: I am trying the "HandlerThread and Looper" pattern, I will let you know. Thank you!

Comment: This worked like a charme with the edits suggested by @AnggrayudiH! Thank you very much!

One side question: why the heck is so hard to achieve this goal? I think this is quite common practice, why does IntentService doesn't live afeter app closure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case:

> Stays alive even after the application closure.

You need to use `Service` instead of `IntentService`, because `IntentService` always kill itself after the code in `onHandleIntent` was completely executed. By calling `startForeground(int notification_id, Notification notification)` in `onStartCommand` method of the `Service`, will make your `Service` still alive without blocking the UI thread. But you need to create a notification to `startForeground` method. And don't forget to call `stopForeground(true)` in `onDestroy()` method of the `Service` after you done with the `Service`. Remember, if the code you want to execute is asynchronous, create a private class `ServiceHandler` which extends `Handler`, and run the code in `handleMessage` method.

An app that implements this pattern is DU Battery Saver.

Comment: I will try this pattern, but I have to specify one thing:

"because IntentService always kill itself after the code in onHandleIntent was completely executed"

That's ok, I would like this behavior! The problem is that IntentService is killed before the end of onHandleIntent, if the app is killed

Comment: This worked like a charme with the help of the docs provided by @Fildor in comments! Thank you very much!

One side question: why the heck is so hard to achieve this goal? I think this is quite common practice, why does IntentService doesn't live after app closure?

Comment: @SimoneChelo, I think you are misunderstanding about the difference between `Service` and `IntentService`. Starting `Service` and `IntentService` are your responsible, and stopping the `Service` is your responsible too, but you don't have any permissions to stop the `IntentService` though you call `stopService()`. Similarity of them is, they never stopped after app closure.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an `IntentService` everything in the `onHandleIntent` method is automatically in a second worker `Thread`. So no need to create the `Thread` yourself. Also make sure, that you do the actual work in `onHandleIntent`. This is where you're supposed to perform the background work.

Also [you should not override onStartCommand](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html)

Comment: As I state in the question, making an `IntentService` make me reach the second goal without using a `Thread`. The problem with that is that the service dies when I kill the application.

The `@Override` of `onStartCommand` is a test of mine, trying not let die the thread but it affects on nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Here the code for re-starting a service if its process is killed on closing the application. In your service, add the following code.

```
@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent){
    Intent restartServiceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), this.getClass());
    restartServiceIntent.setPackage(getPackageName());

    PendingIntent restartServicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 1, restartServiceIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmService.set(
    AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
    SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000,
    restartServicePendingIntent);

    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may Follow the Steps:

**Step 1: Create IntentService**

```
public class DownloadService extends IntentService {
@Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // Gets data from incoming Intent
        String yourDataString = intent.getDataString();
        ...
        // manipulate intent
        ...
    }
}
```

**Stpe 2: Record IntentService in Manifest**

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        ...

        <service
            android:name=".DownloadService"
            android:exported="false"/>
        ...
 <application/>
```

**Step 3: Send Request to IntentService**

```
/* Starting Service */
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SYNC, null, this, DownloadService.class);

/* You can send Extras to IntentService if needed */
intent.putExtra("url", url);
intent.putExtra("receiver", mReceiver);
intent.putExtra("requestId", 101);

startService(intent);
```

> Note: android.permission.INTERNET permission required.

You may check [here](http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html) form more

Comment: I already followed these steps, and they lead me to the second situation of my question: if I kill the app the service dies